# What is the best drums midi recorder?

Tags: audio-recording, midi

I have a Roland TD4 KX2 drum set and I would like to start doing some recordings of what I do.

What is the best option in terms of software to use?

Comment: It would be useful to know, what operating system are you using? Also, do you want to record the MIDI (i.e. just messages about which drum pads you hit when), or the sound produced by your Roland sound module (i.e. recording from the audio outputs instead of the MIDI outputs)?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is for PC and I'm interested in recording the MIDI messages.

Comment: then I'm with Friend of George - give REAPER a try, although any of the major DAWs would be equally suitable (e.g. Cubase, SONAR, ProTools etc)

Comment: Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Mac, [GarageBand](http://www.ehow.com/video_2375347_record-midi_-garageband-tutorial.html) is probably a good place to start.

[Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/index.php) is an inexpensive (only $40 for the home license) program that will work on either PC or Mac.  They have a 30 day fully functional trial, so you can see if you like it.  It's pretty easy to use and there is a [guide on how to setup MIDI in Reaper](http://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/Recording_MIDI).

Comment: It's worth noting that this question - and this answer - generalize to almost any MIDI recording. It's not drum-specific. +1.